# How can i add property from another model when creating a pokemon?

Tags: node.js, express

Hi i am using the pokemon api to make a reactjs app. In my controller i have the following method to create a pokemon:

```
const createPokemon = async (name, hp, attack, defense, speed, height, weight, types, image) => {

  console.log(types)

  const newPokemon = await Pokemon.create({
    name,
    hp,
    attack,
    defense,
    speed,
    height,
    weight,
    image
  })

types.forEach(async (t) => {
  console.log(t)
  const type = await Type.findOne({
    where: {
      name: t,
    }
  })
  console.log(type)
  await newPokemon.addType(type)
})



return newPokemon;

}
```

And this is my list of types:

```
[
  {
    "name": "normal"
  },
  {
    "name": "fighting"
  },
  {
    "name": "flying"
  },
  {
    "name": "poison"
  },
  {
    "name": "ground"
  },
  {
    "name": "rock"
  },
  {
    "name": "bug"
  },
  {
    "name": "ghost"
  },
  {
    "name": "steel"
  },
  {
    "name": "fire"
  },
  {
    "name": "water"
  },
  {
    "name": "grass"
  },
  {
    "name": "electric"
  },
  {
    "name": "psychic"
  },
  {
    "name": "ice"
  },
  {
    "name": "dragon"
  },
  {
    "name": "dark"
  },
  {
    "name": "fairy"
  },
  {
    "name": "unknown"
  },
  {
    "name": "shadow"
  }
]
```

As i create a pokemon i pass all the properties for a pokemon including the type property coming from the Type model.

I am passing `t` as i create it. So i want to find `t` in my list of types and add it to my pokemon.

This is my request:

```
{
    "name": "juann",
    "hp": 61,
    "attack": 64,
    "defense":43,
    "speed": 68,
    "height": 10,
    "types": ["poison", "normal"]

}
```

`console.log(types)`

shows `["poison", "normal"]`

and `console.log(t)` prints `poison` and `normal`

but then i get in my console null and null when `console.log(type)`

Comment: The list of types you are showing are all the possible types right? What does the "types" parameter looks like?

Comment: Could you try to update and try again with this code: `const type = await Type.findOne({ where: { name: t } }).exec()`

Comment: Yes, the list of types are all the possible types. (t) is the type that i am passing in my request. and (type) that shows me null, should be the type that is being find in my list by t. @Feldspatt

Comment: @tukitooo1998 If my recent answer didn't work out, then I think this is caused by passing an async function into types.forEach function; I think you can try to run your code without types.forEach, try to run with regular for...of loop. By the way, you execute .findOne query for each type you received. For better performance you should gennerally look out to decrease your query amount. You can esaily do type finding query with single query. This way your code will also be leaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `forEach` with `await`:

```
const createPokemon = async (
  name,
  hp,
  attack,
  defense,
  speed,
  height,
  weight,
  types,
  image
) => {
  console.log(types);

  const newPokemon = await Pokemon.create({
    name,
    hp,
    attack,
    defense,
    speed,
    height,
    weight,
    image,
  });

  for (const t of types) {
    const type = await Type.findOne({
        where: {
          name: t,
        },
    });
    console.log(type);
    await newPokemon.addType(type);
  }

  return newPokemon;
};
```

Comment: Why shouldnt i be using foreach with await?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach `forEach` expects a synchronous function